# How to calculate derived attributes for dates in CREATE TABLE query. - MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, database, date, derived

I'm setting up a database that will hold all sorts of equipment, and one of the entities holds warranty information for this equipment. One of the attributes I want is an 'Is_Valid' derived attribute that will basically be 'not valid' or 'valid' depending on if the end date of the warranty terms has passed.

I was able to do this in SQL with this query:

```
CREATE TABLE Warranty(
    Warranty_ID     varchar(5),
    Begin_Date      date,
    End_Date        date,
    Terms           varchar(15),
    Is_Valid as (IIF((GetDate() > Begin_Date) AND (GetDate() < End_date), 'valid','not valid')),
    Primary Key (Warranty_ID));
```

However, I've been trying to accomplish this in MySQL, but I cannot get it to work. The only way I got it to work was using an `UPDATE Warranty` query using `case`, but I'd rather the database do this automatically. If I'm understanding something wrong please forgive me, because I am new to database structure and implementation. Thanks.

Comment: AFAIK, you can't do this in MySQL. What you _can_ do, is define either a `ON BEFURE INSERT` & `ON BEFORE UPDATE` trigger, or you can define a `VIEW` with such a `SELECT` query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To begin with, in MySQL dialect `GetDate()` becomes [`CURDATE()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_curdate) and `IIF` becomes [`IF`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/control-flow-functions.html#function_if).

Furthermore, I suggest that you use `BETWEEN` for checking for a range of values: this changes the behavior on Begin_Date and End_Date (the warranty will be valid *including* these dates) but maybe this is also what you'd prefer.

You could use a table and a view on the top of it as the following:

```
CREATE TABLE Warranty(
    Warranty_ID     varchar(5),
    Begin_Date      date,
    End_Date        date,
    Terms           varchar(15),
    Primary Key (Warranty_ID));

CREATE VIEW vw_Warranty AS
SELECT
    Warranty_ID,
    Begin_Date,
    End_Date,
    Terms,
    IF(CURDATE() BETWEEN Begin_Date AND End_date, 'valid', 'not valid') as IS_Valid;
```

Comment: The IF() function (http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/control-flow-functions.html#function_if) is probably a better substitute for IIF(). Otherwise, the answer looks good.

Comment: Thank you @TimBurch, updated my answer with `IF` (and `BETWEEN`).

Comment: I'd never used views before, but I tried yours (after adding 'FROM Warranty' at the end) and it seems to have worked! So, basically if I want to query/pull whether a certain item is out of warranty, I would have to query the vw_Warranty view instead of the Warranty table?

Comment: @astalepancake exactly. The problem will all other ideas (TRIGGER and CHECK) that they are neither e.g. regularly evaluated nor evaluated during a SELECT. A view, however, is re-created every time you access it, so it will always be checked against the current CURDATE().